# Owner drawn taskbar thumbnail preview

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, taskbar

Is there a way to draw the taskbar thumbnail preview on my own, instead of letting Windows draw it for me?

What I need is a dynamic thumbnail; for example, let's say I want the thumbnail to be a reverse of the "real" thumbnail. Any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah you can do with this method: [`DwmSetIconicLivePreviewBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd389410%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Complete example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff819048(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Nice, that might be one step in the right direction, but I'm looking for a dynamic image. See my edited message in a minute.